# Wrong to put an entire page's coding into a LocalizedText.resx Global Resources file with 1 string?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, localization, globalization

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm in the process of adding 5 general languages (not dialects) to my company's website, following the [MSDN tutorial on implicit and explicit localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx)

Can I put my entire aboutus.aspx page code into the LocalizedString.resx and LocalizedString.fr.resx and so on?  Or do I have to make a new string for each block of text?  I put the entire aboutus.aspx main content code into the .resx file, and the page layout worked fine.  But the asp:hyperlinks didn't work.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Do I just have to STOP the string at a hyperlink, and then start a new one?  Is it normal to have 30 strings on an .resx page?

**The bottom line:**

Can I clump this all in a string in a single resource file?  Or would I just put aboutus1 until the first hyperlink, then aboutus2 after the first hyperlink until the 2nd.  The coding is:

```
  We design, 
        engineer, and produce special machine vision error-proofing <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="~/services/" Target="_self">products and services</asp:HyperLink> 
        that create lean factories by improving the quality of manufactured 
products, and by significantly reducing manufacturing costs through advanced 
automation.
```

I know I'd have to put in the aboutus.aspx page wherever I replaced the code:

```
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, aboutus1 %>"></asp:Label>
```

But what about the hyperlinks?  Am I doing this the right way?  I want to be able to get these pages done and overwith!  Thank you for your time in reading this, and any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to use `<asp:HyperLink/>` where you are. It's a server-side tag, which is why it's not working when you try to have it output from the resources. Instead, you should just use a plain HTML `<a>` tag like so:

```
  We design, engineer, and produce special machine vision error-proofing <a  
    href="/services/" Target="_self">products and services</a> 
        that create lean factories by improving the quality of manufactured products, and by significantly reducing manufacturing costs through advanced automation.
```

Note that the URL is different, slightly: it does not have the `~` at the beginning, which is only valid in the server-side tag, anyway.

Comment: Hey, thank you Andrew!  You know, when building this website, I always thought it was more "asp.net 4.0 proper", per se, to use asp:hyperlinks instead of plain html hyperlinks.  That's why I made all my hyperlinks that way.  I truly appreciate you taking the time to read my post and respond!  I'll get to work right now!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Again, thank you very much for explaining it so clearly, Andrew.  I'm not so inept that I don't understand html and some asp.net coding, but the way you explained it, anybody could understand.  The page works perfectly in the 3 languages I've added so far.  And I can take what you said and apply it to my entire website -- there's really no benefit of using the asp:hyperlink for what I'm doing.  I thought it was "asp.net 4.0 proper" to use those types of hyperlinks, but now I realize that's not necessarily the case.  Appreciate you taking the time to respond!